# How to create a self-referencing one-to-many relationship in Flask-SQLAlchemy?

Tags: database, sqlalchemy, one-to-many, flask-sqlalchemy, self-referencing-table

I have a model named `Post`, which has a boolean field called `is_answer`. If the `is_answer` field of a `Post` is True, it's a "question"; otherwise, it's an "answer". I want to create the following question-answer relationship:

One "question" may have many "answer"s, but one "answer" has and only has one "question". Due to the fact that both "question" and "answer" are essentially `Post`s, I think the relationship must be self-referencing.

Here is what I've tried:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    is_question = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    question = db.relationship('Post', backref=db.backref('answer', lazy='dynamic'), uselist=False, lazy='dynamic')
```

The error is:

> ArgumentError: Post.question and back-reference Post.answer are both
>   of the same direction symbol('ONETOMANY'). Did you mean to set
>   remote_side on the many-to-one side ?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `remote_side` argument to create self-referenced relation. More information in [documentaion](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html).

UPDATED: by the way, I think you don't need boolean flag `is_question`, because you can determine questions and answers by checking `post_id` field is `Null` or not.

```
class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('posts.id'))
    question = relationship('Post', remote_side=[id], backref=backref('answers'), uselist=False)
```

Test:

```
session.add(
    Post(
        id=1,
        post_id=None
    )
)
session.add(
    Post(
        id=2,
        post_id=1
    )
)

session.add(
    Post(
        id=3,
        post_id=1
    )
)

session.commit()

question = session.query(Post).get(1)
print question.answers  # output [post2, post3]
answer = session.query(Post).get(2)
print answer.question.id  # output 1

# Receive all answers
print session.query(Post).filter(Post.post_id.isnot(None)).all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below question and answer table.

```
class Answer(Base):
        __tablename__="answers"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        mcq_id = Column(Integer,ForeignKey('questions.id'))
        answer_text = Column(Text())
        is_correct = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    class Question(Base):
        __tablename__="questions"
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        question_text = Column(Text())
        answer_explanation = Column(Text())
        answer_choices = relationship('Answer',
                                     primaryjoin="and_(Question.id == Answer.mcq_id )",
                                     cascade="all, delete-orphan",
                                     foreign_keys=[Answer.mcq_id])
# If you have more than one answers then define this function in your model.
     def has_more_than_one_correct_answer(self):
        count = 0 
        for choice in self.answer_choices:
            if choice.is_correct:
                count = count + 1
        if count > 1:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

You can see the relationship between two tables. And you can access the relationship using `joinedload` or `joinedload_all` if you are using sqlalchemy.

Comment: This is not self-referential